# Storing and retrieving Json object to/from lucene indexes

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I have store a set of json object into the lucene indexes and also want to retrieve it from the index. I am using lucene-3.4.

So is there any library or easy mechanism to make this happen in lucene.

For sample: Json object

```
{
    BOOKNAME1: {
        id:1,
        name:"bname1",
        price:"p1"
    },
    BOOKNAME2: {
        id:2,
        name:"bname2",
        price:"p2"
    },
    BOOKNAME3: {
        id:3,
        name:"bname3",
        price:"p3"
    }
}
```

Any sort of help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: I assume that each entry in the Index is a JSON object, correct me if I'm wrong. Do you want the object's internal components to be searchable? for ex, searching for bname2 would return corresponding json object. Do you want field-based searching? i.e. "id:2", "price:p3" kind of search capability.

Comment: @phani no I dont want to make a search on the json field. Just I want store and retrieve them as json object

Comment: in that case, javanna has already answered which meets your requirements. However, i'm not sure whether you have any unique id associated with each json object.

Comment: Without a unique id it becomes quite impossible to retrieve the stored documents, unless you want to iterate over them all.

Comment: @javana yes i made the key as unique for each of my book and then the json formed was stored into the indexes as string and sorted my issue.

Comment: @phani In my case, I do want to make each object searchable - how can I do this? Basically I want each json object to be a single document.

Comment: Here's my post/question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600396/how-to-treat-json-objects-as-separate-documents-while-indexing-using-lucene @phani

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to search within the json but only store it, you just need to extract the id, which will hopefully be unique. Then your lucene document would have two fields:

- the id (indexed, not necessarily stored)
- the json itself, as it is (only stored)

Once you stored your json in lucene you can retrieve it filtering by id.

On the other hand this is pretty much what [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) does with your documents. You just send some json to it via a REST api. elasticsearch will keep the json as it is and also make it searchable by default. That means you can either retrieve the json by id or search against it, out of the box without having to write any code.

Also, with lucene your documents wouldn't be available till you commit your documents or reopen the index reader, while elasticsearch adds a handy transaction log to it, so that the [GET](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/get.html) is always real time.

Also, elasticsearch offers a lot more: a nice distributed infrastructure, faceting, scripting and more. Check it out!

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend you to index your json object by:

1) Parse your json file. I usually use [json simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).

2) Open an index using IndexWriterConfig

3) Add documents to the index.

4) Commit changes and close the index

5) Run your queries

If you would like to use Lucene Core instead of elasticsearch, I have created a sample project, which gets as an input a file with JSON objects and creates an Index. Also, I have added a test to query the index.

I am using the latest Lucene version (4.8), please have a look here:

http://ignaciosuay.com/getting-started-with-lucene-and-json-indexing/

If you have time, I think it is worth reading "Lucene in Action".

Hope it helps.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer (it deals with the actual question)!

Comment: hello there, I've read your answer and the blog of yours. It's a great article. But my problem occurs in some other case. Could you please take a look at this question of mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874022/indexing-multilevel-json-objects-in-lucene
Thanks