# Indexing Multilevel JSON Objects in Lucene

Tags: java, json, lucene

I am new to Lucene. I have worked on Lucene search using field value pairs in documents. Now there is a requirement to parse some JSON files and Index them up for Lucene search. I have an idea on working with simple form of JSON file according to [this article](http://ignaciosuay.com/getting-started-with-lucene-and-json-indexing/).

But the  [JSON Structure](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3BCHJdXpgr/) I have to work with is little more complex than that. Any kind of idea will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically can linearize your json and then index it as in article you've provided.

For instance, json like this:

```
{"key": {"hello": "world"}}
```

will be transformed into:

```
{"key.hello": "world"}
```