# How to treat JSON objects as separate documents while indexing using Lucene

Tags: java, json, lucene

I have a few JSON files, that look like the one below. I want to treat each JSON object in each file as one document (with "user_id" as a unique identifier). My code treats the entire JSON file as one document. How can I fix this?

```
[
{
"user_id": "john_doeee",
"lon": 204.0,
"lat": 101.0,
"stored" : true,
"hashtag" : "ucriverside"
},
{
"user_id": "carlos_baby",
"lon": 204.0,
"lat": 101.0,
"stored" : true,
"hashtag" : "UCR"
},
{
"user_id": "emmanuel_",
"lon": 204.0,
"lat": 101.0,
"stored" : false,
"hashtag": "riverside"
}
]
```

I think it has something to do with the Document method? 
Here's what I have:

```
static void indexDoc(IndexWriter writer, Path file, long lastModified) throws IOException
{
try (InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(file))
{
     //Create lucene Document
     Document doc = new Document();

     doc.add(new StringField("path", file.toString(), Field.Store.YES));
     doc.add(new LongPoint("modified", lastModified));
     doc.add(new TextField("contents", new String(Files.readAllBytes(file)), Store.YES));

     writer.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.toString()), doc);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's nothing to do with Document method. Lucene have no default ways of understanding that this is JSON file and it should be split up in several Lucene documents. You would need to do it yourself, by using some Java JSON library.

One of many of possibilities could be to use https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java library with code like this:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(" .... ");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    String text = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    doc.add(new TextField("contents", text), Store.YES));
}
```

Of course you're free to use any other JSON libraries like Jackson, GSON, etc.

Comment: Thank you for responding! - Any way you can edit your code to work with JSON Simple?

Comment: @Hana I think it pretty much out of the scope of question