# How to search and analysis JSON data using lucene library

Tags: java, json, search, lucene

I'm writing java based microservice which will receives 1000s of JSON datas like below JSON.
The microservice will perform filter based on some key:value which can be any KEY:VALUE in the json data.
Does **lucene** library provides any search capability for JSON data?. or any other java library provides capability of searching and analysis?.

```
{
  "receiver": "email-logs",
  "status": "firing",
  "alerts": [
    {
      "status": "firing",
      "labels": {
        "alertname": "CPUUsageAbove20%",
        "instance": "node-exporter:9100",
        "job": "node-exporter",
        "monitor": "my-project",
        "severity": "warn",
        "team": "raptors"
      },
      "annotations": {
        "dashboard": "www.prometheus.io",
        "description": "CPU usage on node-exporter:9100 has reached 60"
      },
      "startsAt": "2020-04-30T08:03:17.309164516Z",
      "endsAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "generatorURL": "http://0ab6d9955c65:9090/graph?g0.expr=60+%3E+job%3Anode_cpu_seconds%3Ausage+%3E+20\u0026g0.tab=1",
      "fingerprint": "9c558a8c20c2ba08"
    }
  ],
  "groupLabels": {
    "alertname": "CPUUsageAbove20%",
    "team": "raptors"
  },
  "commonLabels": {
    "alertname": "CPUUsageAbove20%",
    "instance": "node-exporter:9100",
    "job": "node-exporter",
    "monitor": "my-project",
    "severity": "warn",
    "team": "raptors"
  },
  "commonAnnotations": {
    "dashboard": "www.prometheus.io",
    "description": "CPU usage on node-exporter:9100 has reached 60"
  },
  "externalURL": "http://5493399b56dc:9093",
  "version": "4",
  "groupKey": "{}/{team=~\"^(?:(raptors|leafs))$\"}:{alertname=\"CPUUsageAbove20%\", team=\"raptors\"}"
}
```

Comment: This question is probably [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for Stack Overflow. Also, a very similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501285/storing-and-retrieving-json-object-to-from-lucene-indexes). Finally, you may want to consider Solr or ElasticSearch - see the top results of this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=lucene+json).

Comment: Feel free to ask a more specific question about a specific problem you may have with your specific solution (when you get to that point).